# How can I stop a program's input loop only if it receives a special input?

Tags: java, loops

I am looking to have this output:

```
$ java Rp6  
zipcode: 4328024  
4328024: 浜松市立西小学校

zipcode: 9691622  
not found

zipcode: -1  
bye  
$
```

The program should continue accepting zipcodes, until a value lower than 0 is inputted.

For the program I made, it stops after the first zipcode.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rp6 {
    static String[] zipcodes = new String[] { "100", "200", "300" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int zipcodez = scan.nextInt();
        for (String zip : zipcodes) { // loop through zipcodes
            i++;
            if (zipcodez == Integer.parseInt(zip)) {
                System.out.println("found");
                break;
            } else if (i == 3 && zipcodez != Integer.parseInt(zip)) {
                System.out.println("not found");
            } else if (zipcodez <= 0) {
                System.out.println("bye");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of using a loop but not sure where to put the loop. Do you guys have any suggestions?

EDITED: I tried simplifying the code

Comment: Hi Kebabguy. Your question would be much easier to answer if you simplify the example code, since the context about zipcodes is not important to the problem you want solved. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the opinion. I've tried to simplify the code, hopefully the code still makes sense.

Comment: The simplified code actually removed the most telling portion: you have a loop that goes over the file input, but not a loop for user input.  If the goal is `do something until the user inputs x`, then the loop control needs to be around the user input stream, not the file scanner.

Comment: @Thomas I've tried re editing the code but I'm still not sure...

Comment: Look at how many times you read input from `System.in` in your current code.  Right now it's 1.  If you want more than 1, you need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code currently only loops over the zipcodes: `for (String zip : zipcodes)`

If you have code that loads the zipcodes list, you should first loop through the file to load the list. Then once it is loaded, have a second loop on `scan` which will repeatedly get standard input.

Something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rp6 {
    static String[] zipcodes = new String[] { "100", "200", "300" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start an input loop to check the loaded zipcodes
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int zipcodez = 0;
        while (zipcodez >= 0) {
            System.out.print("Zipcode: ");
            zipcodez = scan.nextInt();
            // stop the loop if the user enters -1
            if (zipcodez < 0) {
                System.out.println("bye");
                break;
            }

            // check if the user's zipcode is in zipcodes
            boolean found = false;
            for (String zipcode : zipcodes) {
                if (zipcodez == Integer.parseInt(zipcode)) {
                    System.out.println(zipcode);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something like that but an error saying the variable zipcodez from

while(zipcodez >= 0){

has not been initialized.

Comment: @Kebabguy ah right, change the line with `int zipcodez;` to `int zipcodez = 0;`

Comment: got it. but, everytime i input a zipcode Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Rp6.main(Rp6.java:106) this error came out

Comment: @Kebabguy since I don't have your Eschool code I don't know what is going on there. I have edited my answer to rather match the code from the current version of the question. I hope you can see from this code that you need two loops: one to load your list, and a second loop on the input scanner to repeatedly check the user input.